# inetinfo.exe always appears on Task Manager

Tags: windows, iis, windows-xp, netstat

I just realized that I have a process inetinfo.exe always running on my PC. It seems to be part of IIS. Even if I kill it, it starts again with obviously a different port id.

How can I see in Windows XP which application triggers this process to start?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a tool [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) that can help you to explore all the process and the resource used....

> **Inetinfo.exe (IIS 6.0)**
>
> When IIS 6.0 runs in worker process isolation mode,**Inetinfo.exe is a
> user-mode component that hosts the IIS metabase and that also hosts
> the non-Web services of IIS 6.0,** including the FTP service, the SMTP
> service, and the NNTP service.
>
> Inetinfo.exe depends on IIS Admin service to host the metabase. When IIS 6.0 runs in IIS 5.0
> isolation
> mode, Inetinfo.exe functions much as it did in IIS 5.0. In IIS 5.0
> isolation mode, however, Inetinfo.exe hosts the worker process, which
> runs ISAPI filters, Low-isolation ISAPI extensions, and other Web
> applications.
>
> In IIS6.0, regardless of the application
> isolation mode used, the services that run in Inetinfo.exe run as
> dynamic-link libraries (DLLs) under the Local System account. Because
> a Local System account allows users access to every resource on the
> local computer, use caution when you run services in Inetinfo.exe,
> especially on computers that provide services on the Internet.

From MSDN [InetInfo](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/eaa94a72-77b1-4b4e-abad-314d6b49ba5c.mspx?mfr=true)